# Implementation of pomofocus button

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

how can I implement this div classes that change on-click?
[image: Button animation]

I tried to add border line but it doesn't work to me.
`border-width: 0 0 10px 0;`
This code doesn't change size of div.
Should it be new div or transition of the "button" div?

edit:
vue template code:

`<button role="link" @click="handleClick" class="timerButton" :class="active ? ' active' : ' non-active'" >START</button>` 

css:
`.active { border-width: 0 0 10px 0; }`

Comment: Please show your attempted code. You should be able to do it with a click listener that uses `.classList.toggle()` to add/remove the appropriate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this css code actually makes his job
it is a solution:

```
.active {
    transform: translateY(6px);
}

.non-active {
    box-shadow: rgb(235, 235, 235) 0px 6px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would transition the div using .classList.toggle('start') and then apply padding-bottom and border of the same height...

```
.active {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 20px solid gray;
}
```

I'm guessing you already figured out how to change the words? Please include your code so we can help you better. I hope this works for you!

Comment: yes, I added a variable in html section, because I am using vue `{{ text }}`

Comment: @regor Awesome, does it work for you if you add padding to the bottom as well as a border? :)